# Passing a counter from one Activity to another

Tags: android, bundle, android-activity

I have an class `Voice`, which extends `Activity`, and contains a counter. When the user answers correctly, the counter adds one via `counter++;`

```
public class Voice  extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ListView lv;
    static final int check = 111;
    int counter_score;
    TextView txView;
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    ImageView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letter_a);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSelector);
        txView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        counter_score=0;
    }
```

This score, is bundled and passed on to the next activity "What" within a string "your score is 1".

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        lv.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));

        if(results.contains("hey") || results.contains("a") || results.contains("ay")) {
            //toast referenced to xml the after 400ms
            counter_score++;
            txView.setText("Your Score is" + " " + counter_score);

            AlertDialog dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            dialogBuilder.setTitle("AWSOME");
            dialogBuilder.setMessage("¡Your current score is" + counter_score);
            dialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_mark);
            dialogBuilder.show();

            ourSong = MediaPlayer.create(Voice.this, R.raw.rightsound2);
            ourSong.start();
            Thread timer = new Thread() {
                public void run(){
                try {
                    sleep(2500);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    String score = txView.getText().toString();
                    Bundle keeper = new Bundle();
                    keeper.putString("key", score);
                    Intent putScore = new Intent(Voice.this, What.class);
                    putScore.putExtras(keeper);
                    startActivity(putScore);
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();
    }
}
```

The next `Activity`, `What`, gets this `Bundle` and displays it fine using `setText(gotScore)`

```
public class What  extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ListView lv;
    static final int check = 111;
    private int counter_score;
    TextView txView;
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    ImageView display;
    String gotScore;

    String classes[] = {"What", "Pagina", "What", "example3", "example4", "example5", 
                        "example6"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letter_b);
        initialize();
        Bundle gotKeeper = getIntent().getExtras();
        gotScore = gotKeeper.getString("key");
        txView.setText(gotScore);
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvVoiceReturn);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonSelector);
        txView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

..this is when things go bad :(

On `What` I have another question tied to a counter as well. When the user answers correctly the counter adds one via `counter++;` and it does. However, it changes the `txview` `string` to "your score is 1". I can't get it to add 1 to the counter result passed from the previous activity within the string, so that the counter on `What` reads "your score is 2". This gets passes to the next activity in `Bundle keeper`, which holds the aggregate score.

I've read a few tutorials on passing an `int` verses a `string`, but some of the code they use like `getInt` is not recognized. I'm stumped.

Comment: It is far easier to go from int to string, so you want to store the integer.  You could extend the Application class and store your global variables there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're bundling and passing to the What activity is not the counter but the string "Your score is 1". If you want to increment that number in the next activity then you should be sending just the integer value and constructing whatever string you need there instead.

> I ve read a few tuts on passing an int vs a string..but some of the code they use like getInt is not recognized..anywho Im stumped..

I'm not too sure I know what you mean by getInt() is not recognized. In any case, make things easier for yourself when passing counter from one activity to another. If it is an int and you plan on manipulating like an int in the receiving activity then add it to the bundle as an int. For example:

```
    Bundle keeper = new Bundle();
    keeper.putInt("key", counter_score);
```

And retrieve it from the bundle with:

```
    Bundle gotKeeper = getIntent().getExtras();
    int score = gotKeeper.getInt("key");
```

Comment: Hey guys thank you so much to everyone for their input and sugestions.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>What if you make a "global" class to be shared across the different activities, and use it to keep the variables used "in sync"?</strike>

For example - Globals.java:

```
public class Globals {

  public int counter_score; 

}
```

And then reference that variable using `Globals.counter_score`

You can of course also use that shared class for other variables and functions as well - for example common operations.

## Update

As the commenters pointed out, this method isn't particularily good - I forgot that the code is simply referenced, and doesn't "live" on its own to keep information for the other activities (thanks for correcting me on that one, I'm still learning...)

Something that COULD work better, though, is to pass the current state of the counter_score variable in the intent when you launch your second activity - for example:

```
IntentToLaunchTheOtherActivity( counter_score );
```

And then maybe pass the variable back to the previous activity if it's changed afterwards...

Comment: Well this doesn't work unless all of your variables are static.  This solution still requires all of your other classes to have an instance of Globals.. and all of those instances will have their own variables.

Comment: Plus, there's no guarantee that the system won't kill your app and reap the global variables between activities.  That would be a rare event, but it could happen.  If you need to make sure it never happens, then you'll want to store your counter in a file somewhere, or pass it back and forth in intents.

Answer (score 0):

I got it work. Essentially I needed to what what TJ Third suggested converting `keeper.putString("key", counter_score);` to `keeper.putInt("key", counter_score);`, I also needed to convert the bundle being received to an int within the "What" activity. Within "What" activity I renamed `int counter_score;` and `int gotKeeper;`(this was String gotKeeper) then instead of calling counter_score =0; now that the bundle passed is an int,I called counter_score = gotKeeper; under initialize(); so the counter score equals the result generated from the previous activity "Voice".

Now when the user answers correctly, counter++; adds one to the existing counter_score and bundles it and send it to the next activity, and rinse a repeat.

```
static final int check = 111;
    int counter_score;
    TextView txView;
    MediaPlayer ourSong;
    ImageView display;
    int gotKeeper;


    String classes[] = {"What", "Pagina", "What", "example3", "example4", "example5", 
    "example6"};


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.letter_b);
        initialize();
        Bundle gotKeeper = getIntent().getExtras();
        gotKeeper = gotScore.getInt("key");
        counter_score = gotKeeper;
```

Again thnx to everyone for your suggestions and insight.Huge help to a newbie.

Comment: If you have an update to your progress, please edit your question and write the updated information there. If a particular answer, such as mine was helpful in resolving your issue then please accept the answer. [Refer to the FAQ for more information on StackOverflow's guidelines and etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)